# Parsing node-specific XML Using JQuery

Tags: xml, jquery

There have been a lot of other posts related to this but I can't seem to find the answer to my question. I'm trying to parse an XML file of the following form to return only the items under the 'subGroup' node.

Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<resultsGroup>
  <item>
      <id></id>
      <title></title>
      <description></description>
  </item>
  <item>
      <id></id>
      <title></title>
      <description></description>
  </item>
  <subGroup>
      <item>
          <id></id>
          <title></title>
          <description></description>
      </item>  
      <item>
          <id></id>
          <title></title>
          <description></description>
      </item>  
      <item>
          <id></id>
          <title></title>
          <description></description>
      </item>  
  </subGroup>
</resultsGroup>
```

And here is currently what I'm using to parse it:

```
$.get(url,{},function(data){
    $('item',data).each(function(i){
        var id = $(this).find("id").text();
        var title = $(this).find("title").text();
        var description = $(this).find("description").text();

        list.append('<li>' + id + ':' + title + ':' + description + '</li>');
    });
});
```

The problem is that the items listed under the 'resultsGroup' are also being selected by $('item',data).each(). I'd appreciate it if someone could explain how to select just those elements under a specific node, in this case the 'subGroup' node.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $('subGroup>item',data)

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks Doug. Is there somewhere online that explains JQuery XML selectors in more detail? I couldn't find anything and I'd love to better understand them. Thanks again!

Comment: jQuery no longer supports XPath, but its CSS selectors work with XML. See http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Comment: Nice Doug- this was a hard one to find

Comment: @DougDomeny, Is there any way to read data based on the attributes. For instance,                                                `<subGroup>
      <item id = "1">
          <title></title>
          <description type="string" label="Details"></description>
      </item></subGroup>`

Comment: @Ahamed, yes, there are many jQuery operators for use with attributes. For example, `$('subGroup>item[id="1"]',data)` to select elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value. See [jQuery Selector Reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).